# Defiantjs if no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm using [defiantjs](http://www.defiantjs.com/) to perform json searches.

```
result = JSON.search(data, '//*[name="Gheorghe"]');
```

If the value is not found in the json I get an error `Cannot read property 'Gheorghe' of undefined`.

Is there a way to return something else if no search string is matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    //check for return value (search result or falsy value)
    result = JSON.search(data, '//*searchValue') || 'not found';
} catch (e) {
    //if there was an error in the request
    console.log(e);
    result = 'Not found. But dude, we could not even finish your request, as we encountered the following error: ' + e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses) statement**

> *The try...catch statement marks a block of statements to try, and specifies a response, should an exception be thrown.*

**Example**

> *In the following example, code in the try block can potentially throw three exceptions: **TypeError**, **RangeError**, and **EvalError** (Error types: `EvalError`, `InternalError`, `RangeError`, `ReferenceError`, `SyntaxError`, `TypeError`, `URIError`). When an exception occurs, control transfers to the appropriate catch clause. If the exception is not one of the specified exceptions and an unconditional catch clause is found, control transfers to that catch clause.*

```js
var result;
try{
  alert(result.id);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
    e='This is my custom  type-error message instead of "Cannot read property..."';
    } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
    e='This is my custom  range-error message instead of "Cannot read property..."';
    } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
    e='This is my custom  eval-error message instead of "Cannot read property..."';
    } else {
   // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    e='This is my custom  unspecified-error message instead of "Cannot read property..."';
  }
  console.log("Error!",e); // prints to console custom error message
}

alert(result.id); // prints to console default error message result is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use

```
if(typeof(JSON.search(data, '//*[name="Gheorghe"]')) !== 'undefined') {
  result = JSON.search(data, '//*[name="Gheorghe"]');
}
else {
  //something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defiant.js, the third party library is supposed to take care of this issue. I take your word that they are not.

In that case, there are two ways to solve this issue.

1. To modify the library to return undefined when no results are found - this way is not recommended as it will be problematic to other developers who are working on the code base and also to maintain versioning of the library using bower/npm.
2. To use try catch around the implementation - this is the ideal way to solve this problem as you don't have to make changes to the third party library and you can get an easy trigger to check if the error from the try block is equal to `"Cannot read property 'Gheorghe' of undefined"`, you can run your preferred callback.

This is the solution I would recommend.

```
var name = "Gheorge";
try {
   result = JSON.search(data, '//*[name="' + name + '"]');
} 
catch (error === "Cannot read property '" + name + "' of undefined") {
   // As there could be any type of error from the function JSON.search
   console.log(error);
   yourErrorHandler(error);
}
```